# singlelogout post binding not working in php onelogin library

Tags: php, saml-2.0, okta, onelogin

I'm using the **onelogin** PHP library for okta integration in my SP.

In the settings file, my code is

```
'singleLogoutService' => array (
                'binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST',
                'url' => 'https://dev-178905-admin.oktapreview.com/app/abcincpreview_pbdev/ekk8663bx8jL1f4gM0h7/slo/saml'
            )
```

I use a HTTP-POST binding. However, a SAML tracer shows that the request is sent as GET method to IDP. The okta process requires a POST method for logout.
Any idea what's going wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Clarified wording.

Answer (score 2):

The php-saml toolkit only supports LogoutRequest and LogoutResponse on the HTTP-Redirect binding.

It seems that Okta only support LogoutRequest on HTTP-POST binding.

So you have 2 alternatives:

- Use simplesamlphp that supports HTTP-POST binding for Logouts.
- Extend the php-saml toolkit.

Comment: How to extend php-saml toolkit

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml/issues/142#issuecomment-240454512